# Symfony CLI doesn't find all the php versions on my system

Tags: php, symfony, windows-11, symfony6, symfony-cli

I created a Symfony 6 project locally on my PC (Windows 11 Entreprise v.21H2) and I want to use a specific version of PHP.
I know that we can use different versions by creating a `.php-version` file in the project root.

So I did this command `symfony local:php:list` and it only shows Wamp64 and Xampp php that **I don't want to use**. I have many other versions inside `C:/php/` folder. For this project, I need to use **php 8.0.19**.

My question is : how can I select php 8.0.19 if even Symfony CLI doesn't show it in the list ? And why ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the list? There is a command for it, similar to list, I think it’s called `local:php:refresh`. If that doesn’t help, you should probably check if the binary is registered in PATH in your local environment variable.

Comment: Yes I did the refresh and nothing changed. What do you mean by the "binary" ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear. If you want to use php.exe in any of the directories in your screenshot from anywhere else, you have to add the directory, e.g. “C:\php\8.0.19\” to the PATH variable (or call the full path).Maybe the Symfony CLI will better find the other version by adding it to the PATH

Comment: I did it too, it was my first reaction when I saw the issue. The console uses the good version of php when I check by doing `php -v` but Symfony still doesn't find it...

Comment: It looks like someone else reported the same issue: https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/78 I don’t have a PC for the next week, so I can’t look at the code in more detail, but I would guess the location Fabien linked either needs fixing or you need to check how it finds the PHP versions and make some changes

Comment: Here is how it works : https://github.com/symfony-cli/phpstore/blob/main/discovery_windows.go and I opened a ticket on the github : https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/182 . In the meantime, I work with wampserver...